# Evaluate the Fourier coefficient

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Now I want to figure out the following problem: Suppose that $f\in L^1(-\pi,\pi)$. Define $F(x)$ as
\begin{align}
F(x) = \int_{-\pi}^x (f(t)-c_0(f)) dt\,,~x\in[-\pi,\pi]
\end{align}
where $c_n(f)$ is
\begin{align}
c_n(f) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{-inx}dx\,.
\end{align}
Then evaluate $c_0(F)$.

I tried to solve this problem as follows. Using Fubini's theorem, we have
\begin{align}
2\pi c_0(F) &= \int_{-\pi}^\pi F(x) dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\pi}^x (f(t)-c_0(f)) dt dx \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{t}^\pi dx (f(t)-c_0(f)) dt = \int_{-\pi}^\pi (\pi-t)(f(t)-c_0(f)) dt\,.
\end{align}
Since we have $\int_{-\pi}^\pi (f(t)-c_0(f))dt=0$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi (\pi-t)(f(t)-c_0(f))dt=\int_{-\pi}^\pi -t(f(t)-c_0(f))dt=\int_{-\pi}^\pi -tf(t)dt = 2\pi c_0(F)\,.
\end{align}
After progressing this point, it is currently stuck. What can I do to get better results here?

Comment: why don't you write $f \sim c_0+\sum_{n \ne 0}c_ne^{inx}$ which holds in the $L^1$ sense for example, so you can integrate term by term, get $F$ and then integrate once more and all the $e^{inx}, n \ne 0$ terms go away etc

Comment: @Conrad But then we have just the identity relation $\int_{-\pi}^\pi F(x) dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi c_0(F) dx$, doesn't it? Or... Do you intend that I have $F(x) = c_0(F) + \sum_{n\neq0} c_n(f)e^{inx}/(in)$ and integrate once more?

Comment: @Conrad Oh now I think I have solved it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have solved the OP using Conrad's suggestion. Since $F\in W^1_1(-\pi,\pi)$ clearly and $F(\pi)=F(-\pi)=0$, hence it is periodic, therefore we can say that the Fourier series of $F$ converges to $F$ pointwisely, i.e.,
\begin{align}
F(x)=c_0(F)+\sum\limits_{n\neq 0}\frac{c_n(f)}{in}e^{inx}\,.
\end{align}
Then, we have
\begin{align}
F(x)-F(-\pi)=\sum\limits_{n\neq0}\frac{c_n(f)}{in}(e^{inx}-e^{-in\pi})\,.
\end{align}
Integrate both sides from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ yields,
\begin{align}
2\pi c_0(F) &= \sum\limits_{n\neq0}\frac{c_n(f)}{in}\int_{-\pi}^\pi (e^{inx} - e^{-in\pi}) dx = 0\,,
\end{align}
since $\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{inx}dx=0$ for $n\neq0$ and $\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-in\pi} dx = (-1)^n2\pi$; hence the sum of all the pairs $-n$ and $n$ vanish because of the term $(in)^{-1}$.